# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln\left[ \tan\left ( \frac{\theta}{2}\right) \right ]^2 K\left ( \sin\theta \right )\text{d}\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-series, closed-form, elliptic-integrals

Let us define $K(x)$ as complete elliptic integral of the first kind, where $x$ is elliptic modulus. A possible closed-form is ($G$ denotes Catalan's constant.)
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\ln\left[ \tan\left (  \frac{\theta}{2}\right)  \right ]^2
K\left ( \sin\theta \right )\text{d}\theta
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4G }{8\pi}.
$$
It looks like a "product" of two solvable integrals (both are elementary):
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\ln\left[ \tan\left (  \frac{\theta}{2}\right)  \right ]^2\text{d}\theta
=\frac{\pi^3 }{8}$$
and
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
K\left ( \sin\theta \right )\text{d}\theta
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{16\pi}.
$$

---

*Question*:
How can we evaluate the integral? I try to utilize the Fourier series $K(\sin\theta)
=\pi\sum_{n\ge0} \frac{\left ( \frac12 \right )_n^2 }{(n!)^2} 
\sin\left ( \left ( 4n+1 \right )\theta  \right )$ to prove, but seems not to go well. I appreciate for your help.

---

*An Interesting Observation*:
We find
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\ln\left[ \tan\left (  \frac{\theta}{2}\right)  \right ]^4
K\left ( \sin\theta \right )\text{d}\theta
=\frac{3\,\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4}{4\pi}(G^2+\beta(4))
$$
where $\beta(.)$ is Dirichlet's $\beta$ function.

Comment: Using series will probably never give this nice result.

Comment: We have some more questions around regarding values of integrals involving $K$, please share the source of the identities. In a book or paper, such identities have their direct neighborhood, often suggesting a way to attack the integrals, also they come with useful identities. Also, for a structural or systematic way to see these integrals, there is always a benefit of already having all data at one place, please understand, i suppose for your purposes all these posts are not individual integrals with a dead end computation. If numerical tools suggest the identities, please also mention them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \log^{2n} (\tan \frac{x}{2}) K(\sin x) dx = \int_0^1 \frac{2 \log^{2n} t}{1+t^2} K(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}) dt$$
Their values can be extracted by differentiating $$\tag{*}\int_0^1 \frac{t^{4a} + t^{-4a}}{1+t^2} K(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}) dt = \frac{\pi}{8}\cot(\pi(\frac{1}{4}-a))\frac{\Gamma \left(a+\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{\Gamma \left(a+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2} \quad -1/4<\Re(a)<1/4$$

I give two different proofs of $(*)$, I come up with the longer proof first.

---

*First proof of $(*)$*: using quadratic transformation $(1+t^2)K(t^2) = K(2t/(1+t^2))$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 \frac{t^{4a}}{1+t^2} K(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}) dt &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 t^{2a-1/2} K(t) dt \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi}{1+4a}{_3F_2}(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4} + a; 1, \frac{5}{4} + a; 1)
\end{aligned}$$
here we noted that $K(t)$ is a $_2F_1$. Using [third formulas here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/17/02/06/) gives
$${_3F_2}(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4} + a; 1, \frac{5}{4} + a; 1) = \frac{4 a+1}{4 a-1} {_3F_2(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4} - a; 1, \frac{5}{4} - a; 1)} +\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}-a\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}-a\right) \Gamma \left(a+\frac{3}{4}\right)}$$
we see the $a$ in $_3F_2$ becomes $-a$, giving $(*)$. Q.E.D.

---

*Second proof of $(*)$*: It's much longer. See edit history.

Comment: How was $G$ "discovered"? Is there some standard combinatoric algorithm for finding such 'complementary' $G$?

Comment: @FShrike $G$ is found by creative telescoping algorithm. You might want to learn about theory of WZ (Wilf-Zeilberger) pairs on combinatorics first.

Comment: Can $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(1/2)_k^2}{(1)_k^2} \frac{1}{2n+2k+1}$ be transferred?

Comment: @SetnessRamesory  what do you mean by "transferred"?

Answer (score 1):

By expanding $K(k)$, we deduce
$$
\,_5F_4\left ( 
\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac12,\frac12;
1,\frac54,\frac54,\frac54;1 \right )=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right)^4}{16\pi^2}G,
$$
$$
\,_7F_6\left ( 
\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac12,\frac12;
1,\frac54,\frac54,\frac54,\frac54,\frac54;1 \right )=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right)^4}{32\pi^2}(G^2+\beta(4)).
$$

Comment: How did you calculate that?