# Evaluate $I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}k^a(1-k^2)^bK(k)\text{d}k$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

With the interests of
$$
I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}k^a(1-k^2)^bK(k)\text{d}k,
$$
where $K(k)$ [represents the complete elliptic integral with modulus $k$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) and $K^\prime(k)$ its complementary,
many $I(a,b)$ for rational $a,b$ are evaluated. The methodologies are as follows:

$\textbf{1.Hypergeometric Representations}$
Expanding $K(k)$, we obtain(conditions omitted)
$$I(a,b)=\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\Gamma(b+1)\Gamma\left ( \frac{a+1}{2}  \right ) }{
\Gamma\left ( \frac{a+3}{2}+b  \right ) }
{}_3F_2\left ( \frac{1}{2},\frac12,\frac{a+1}{2};\frac{a+3}{2}+b,1;1    \right ).$$
Note that $I(a,b+1)=I(a,b)-I(a+2,b)$.
Apparently, supposing $\frac{a+3}{2}+b=\frac12$ i.e. $b=-1-\frac{a}{2}$, it simplifies to
$$
I\left ( a,-1-\frac{a}{2}  \right ) 
=\frac{\cos\left ( \frac{\pi a}{2}  \right ) }{4\pi} 
\Gamma\left ( -\frac{a}{2}  \right )^2\Gamma\left ( \frac{a+1}{2}  \right )^2.
$$
Also,
$$
I(1,b)=\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\Gamma\left ( b+1 \right )^2 }{
\Gamma\left ( b+\frac32 \right )^2}.
$$
Some hypergeometric transformations are applicable to the given ${}_3F_2$. For instances, from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648138/) we have
$$I(s,0)+I(-s-1,0)
=-\frac{\pi}{4}\tan\left ( \frac{\pi s}{2}  \right ) 
\frac{\Gamma\left ( -\frac{s}{2} \right )^2 }{
\Gamma\left ( \frac{1-s}{2}  \right )^2 }.$$
(add on *May 20th, 23*) Applying Dixon's ${}_3F_2$ Theorem, that allowed us to proceed further. Explicitly, as $a+b=-1/2$,
$$
I(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2}{8\sqrt{2\pi} } 
\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1+a}{2}  \right ) \Gamma\left ( \frac12-a \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac14-\frac{a}{2} \right )  }{\Gamma\left ( \frac34-\frac{a}{2}  \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{1-a}{2}  \right )  }.
$$
If $a-2b=1,\Re(a)>0$,
$$
I(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2}{8\sqrt{\pi} }
\frac{\Gamma\left ( 1+\frac{a}{2}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac{1+a}{2}  \right )^3}{
\Gamma(1+a)\Gamma\left ( \frac{3}{4}+\frac{a}{2}   \right )^2 },
$$
which gives the evaluation
$$
I\left ( -\frac{5}{6},-\frac{11}{12}   \right )
=\frac{3^{3/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4  }{4\pi\cdot2^{2/3}}.
$$

$\textbf{2.Contour Integration}$
We have
$$
I(a,b)+\cos(b\pi)I(-a-2b-1,b)
+\sin(b\pi)I\left ( 2b+1,-\frac{a}{2}-b-1  \right ) 
+\sin\left ( \frac{\pi a}{2}  \right )I\left ( a,-\frac{a}{2}-b-1  \right )=0
,$$
and
$$
\cos(b\pi)I\left ( 2b+1,-\frac{a}{2}-b-1  \right ) 
=\cos\left ( \frac{\pi a}{2}  \right )
I\left ( a,-\frac{a}{2}-b-1 \right )+\sin\left ( \pi b \right )
I(-a-2b-1,b).
$$
Setting $a=-5/6,b=-11/12$, producing
\begin{aligned}
I\left ( \frac{5}{3},-\frac{11}{12}   \right ) 
& = \sqrt{3}\left ( \sqrt{3}+1  \right ) I\left ( -\frac56,\frac13 \right )\\
& =\frac{3^{1/4}\left ( \sqrt{3}+1  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4  }{4\pi\cdot 2^{1/6}},
\end{aligned}
where the second equality is owing to the former identity for $a+b=-1/2$.
Another less obvious one is,
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{k^{2/3}K(k)}{\left ( 1-k^2 \right )^{2/3} }
\text{d} k=\frac{3^{3/4}\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{24\pi\cdot2^{1/6}  }.
$$

$\textbf{3.Modular Forms(1)}$
The basic idea is to construct a modular form expressed by Jacobi $\vartheta$ functions and compute its $L$-value. For example, setting $q=\exp(-\pi K^\prime(k)/K(k))$
$$
f(q)=\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}
(-1)^m\left [ 3\left ( m+\frac16 \right )^2-n^2 \right ]
q^{3\left ( m+\frac16 \right )^2+n^2 }.$$
We have
$$f(q)=\frac{2^{2/3}k^{1/6}(1-k^2)^{1/12}(1-2k^2)}{
3\pi^3}K(k)^3.$$
And
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(q)\text{d}x
=\frac{1}{\pi^2} \sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}
\frac{(-1)^m}{\left ( \sqrt{3}\left ( m+\frac16 \right )+ni   \right )^2 }.$$
Therefore it's sufficient to show that
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(2k^2-1)K(k)}{k^{5/6}(1-k^2)^{11/12}}\text{d}k
=\frac{3^{7/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6  }{
16\pi^2\cdot2^{1/3}  },$$
and therefore,
$$
I\left ( \frac{7}{6},-\frac{11}{12}   \right )
=\frac{3^{3/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4  }{8\pi\cdot2^{2/3}}
+\frac{3^{7/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6  }{
32\pi^2\cdot2^{1/3}  }.
$$
Which also gives
$$
I\left ( -\frac{5}{6},\frac{1}{12}   \right )
=\frac{3^{3/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4  }{8\pi\cdot2^{2/3}}
-\frac{3^{7/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6  }{
32\pi^2\cdot2^{1/3}  },
$$
with
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left ( 1-k^{12} \right )^{\frac{1}{12}}
K\left ( k^6 \right )\text{d}k =\frac{3^{3/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4  }{48\pi\cdot2^{2/3}}
-\frac{3^{3/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6  }{64\pi^2\cdot2^{1/3}  }.
$$
However, this usually only gives linear equation among two $I(a,b)$. Apart from
$$I\left(-\frac34,0\right)=\frac{\left ( 3+\sqrt{2}  \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac18 \right )^2\Gamma\left ( \frac38 \right )^2  }{
48\pi\sqrt{2} },$$
$$
I\left(-\frac14,0\right)=\frac{\left ( 3-\sqrt{2}  \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac18 \right )^2\Gamma\left ( \frac38 \right )^2  }{
48\pi\sqrt{2} },$$
they can be:
$$
2I\left ( -\frac13,-\frac{11}{12} \right )
-I\left ( \frac53,-\frac{11}{12} \right ) 
=\frac{3^{7/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6  }{
8\cdot2^{5/6}\pi^2  },
$$
$$
4I\left ( -\frac23,-\frac{17}{24} \right )
+I\left ( \frac43,-\frac{17}{24} \right ) 
=\frac{\left ( \sqrt{2}-1  \right )^{\frac32}
\left ( \sqrt{3} +\sqrt{2}  \right )^{\frac32}\cdot3^{\frac14}
\left ( 1+\left ( 2-\sqrt{3}  \right )
\left ( \sqrt{3} -\sqrt{2}  \right )   \right )^2 }{8\cdot2^{\frac13}\pi}
\Gamma\left ( \frac{1}{24} \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{5}{24} \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{7}{24} \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{11}{24} \right ).
$$
Gathering all information we know about $I(a,b)$, we obtain two additional
values:
\begin{aligned}
&I\left ( -\frac13,-\frac{11}{12} \right )
=\frac{3^{1/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3} \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4  }{8\pi\cdot 2^{1/6}}
+\frac{3^{7/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6  }{
16\cdot2^{5/6}\pi^2  },\\
&I\left ( -\frac13,\frac{1}{12}  \right )
=-\frac{3^{1/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3} \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4  }{8\pi\cdot 2^{1/6}}
+\frac{3^{7/4}\left ( 1+\sqrt{3}  \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6  }{
16\cdot2^{5/6}\pi^2  }.
\end{aligned}

$\textbf{4.Modular Forms(2)}$
It's also possible to [prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661953/) that
\begin{aligned}
&\color{purple}{\left(\frac2\pi\right)^2\int_{0}^{1} \left ( \frac{K^\prime}{K}  \right )^{s-1}
\frac{(1-2k^2)K(k)}{\sqrt{k}(1-k^2)^{3/4}}\text{d}k
=2^{2s}\pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)[L_8(s)L_{-8}(s-2)+L_{-8}(s)L_{8}(s-2)]},\\
&\color{purple}{\left(\frac2\pi\right)^2\int_{0}^{1} \left ( \frac{K^\prime}{K}  \right )^{s-1}
\frac{\sqrt{k}K(k)}{(1-k^2)^{1/4}}\text{d}k
=2^{2s-1}\pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)[L_8(s)L_{-8}(s-2)-L_{-8}(s)L_{8}(s-2)]}.
\end{aligned}
Also note that $a=-\frac12,b=-\frac34=-1-\frac{a}{2}$, we derive
\begin{aligned}
&I\left ( \frac32,-\frac34 \right ) 
=\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{2} }+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{8\pi\sqrt{2} },\\
&I\left ( \frac12,-\frac14 \right ) 
=\frac{\pi^2}{4\sqrt{2} }.
\end{aligned}

$\textbf{5.Fourier-Legendre Expansions}$
Similarly to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267168/). But most results aren't newly-created.

---

The questions come here:

1. Whether we can find more closed-forms for single $I(a,b)$?
2. Can we come up with more ways to cope with $I(a,b)$?

**Remark**: The remained question is  [$I\left(\frac34,-\frac38\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4682907/), which seems to be unable to prove in ways listed above.

Answer (score 1):

A new one:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{k} K(k)\text{d}k
=2-\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^4 }{\pi}.
$$
*Proof.*
We have
$$
\int_0^1k^sK(k)\text{d}k
+\int_{0}^{1}k^{-s-1}K(k)\text{d}k
=-\frac{\pi}{4}\tan\left ( \frac{\pi s}{2}  \right )  
\frac{\Gamma\left (- \frac{s}{2}  \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1-s}{2}  \right )^2 },
$$
$$
(n+1)^2\int_{0}^{1}k^{n+1}K(k)\text{d}k
-n^2\int_{0}^{1}k^{n-1}K(k) \text{d}k=1.
$$
Substituting $s=1/2,n=-1/2$ respectively gives two equations. Hence the result.$\square$

---

The following results hold:
\begin{aligned}
&I\left ( s-1,-\frac{1+s}{2}  \right ) 
=\sin\left ( \frac{\pi s}{2}  \right ) \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{s}2 \right )^2\Gamma\left ( \frac{1-s}{2}  \right )^2 }{4\pi},\\
&I\left ( s-1,\frac12-s \right ) 
=2^{-s-2}\sin\left ( \frac{\pi s}{2}  \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{s}2 \right )^2 
\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34-\frac{s}2 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2},\\
&I\left ( s-1,-\frac12-s \right ) 
=2^{-s-3}\sin\left ( \frac{\pi s}{2}  \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{s}{2}  \right )^2
\left ( \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14-\frac{s}2 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2} 
+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34-\frac{s}2 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2}  \right ),\\
&I\left ( s+1,-\frac12-s \right ) 
=2^{-s-3}\sin\left ( \frac{\pi s}{2}  \right )
\Gamma\left ( \frac{s}{2}  \right )^2
\left ( \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14-\frac{s}2 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2} 
-\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34-\frac{s}2 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2}  \right ),\\
&I\left ( -2s,\frac{s}{2}  \right ) 
=2^{-s-5/2}\Gamma\left ( \frac{s}{2}  \right )^2
\left ( 
\sin\left ( \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi s}{2}   \right )  
 \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14-\frac{s}2 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2}
-\sin\left ( \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi s}{2}   \right )  
 \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34-\frac{s}2 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2}
\right),\\
&I\left ( -2s-2,\frac{s}{2}  \right ) 
=-2^{-s-7/2}\sin\left ( \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi s}2  \right )
\frac{\Gamma\left ( -\frac14-\frac{s}2 \right )^2\Gamma\left (1+\frac{s}2  \right )^2  }{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2 },\\
&I\left ( -2s-2,\frac{s}{2}+1  \right ) 
=2^{-s-5/2}\Gamma\left ( \frac{s}{2}  \right )^2
\left ( 
\frac{2s^2+4s+1}{(2s+1)^2} \sin\left ( \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi s}{2}   \right )  
 \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac34-\frac{s}2 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac34 \right )^2}
-\sin\left ( \frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi s}{2}   \right )  
 \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14-\frac{s}2 \right )^2 }{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2}
\right).
\end{aligned}
For instance,
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2/3}(1-x^2)^{5/6}K(x)\text{d}x
=\frac{27\cdot3^{1/4}\left ( 12\sqrt{3}-13  \right )\Gamma\left(\frac23\right)^6 }{196\pi^2\sqrt{2} }.$$

Answer (score 0):

Others:

1. For $0<\Re(s)<1$,
   $$\int_{0}^{1} x^{s-1}\left(1-x^2\right)^{-s}\left(1+x^2\right)K(x)^2\text{d}x
   =2^{-s}\sin\left ( \frac{\pi s}{2}  \right )^2
   \frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{s}2 \right )^3
   \Gamma\left ( \frac{1-s}{2}  \right )^3 }{8\pi^{3/2}}.$$
2. For $-1<\Re(s)<1$,
   $$
   \int_{0}^{1} x^s\left ( 1-x^2 \right ) ^{-\frac{s+1}{2} }K(x)K^\prime(x)\text{d}x
   =\frac{\pi^2}{8\sin\left (\frac{\pi s}2 \right ) }
   \left ( \mathscr{G}(s)-\mathscr{G}(-s) \right ),
   $$
   where $$\mathscr{G}(s)=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac{1-s}{2}  \right )^2}{
   \Gamma\left (\frac{2-s}{2}   \right )^2 }
   \,_4F_3\left ( \frac12,\frac12,\frac{1-s}{2},\frac{1-s}{2};
   1,1-\frac{s}{2},1-\frac{s}{2}  ;1   \right ).$$