# Series related to $\,_{2p+1}F_{2p}\left(\left\{\frac{a}{2}\right\}_{2p-1},a,\frac12;a+\frac{1}{2},\left\{1+\frac{a}{2}\right\}_{2p-1};1\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, contour-integration, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

Similar things have been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648138/). As an example, let $p=2,a=1/3$ to have
$$
{}_5F_4\left ( \frac16,\frac16,\frac16,\frac13,\frac12;
\frac56,\frac76,\frac76,\frac76;1 \right )=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( \frac13 \right )_n\left ( \frac12 \right )_n  }{
\left ( \frac56 \right )_n (1)_n} \frac{1}{(6n+1)^3}=
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^3\left ( 9\psi^{(1)}\left ( \frac13 \right ) -4\pi^2 \right )  }{
144\pi\sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{3}  }.
$$
The manipulation is essentially consonant with what had done in the mentioned question. We have
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \left ( x^{s-1} +x^{a-s-1}\right ) 
{}_2F_1\left ( a,\frac12;a+\frac{1}{2};x  \right )\text{d}x
=\cot(\pi s)\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma\left ( a+\frac12 \right ) 
\Gamma(a-s)\Gamma\left ( \frac12-s \right )  }{
\Gamma(a)\Gamma(1-s)\Gamma\left ( a+\frac12-s \right ) }
$$
whenever the integral converges(actually we can add $x^n$ terms inside to make it converge). By differentiating both sides, one can evaluate
$$
\int_{0}^{1} x^{\frac{a}2-1}\ln(x)^{2p-2}
{}_2F_1\left ( a,\frac12;a+\frac{1}{2};x  \right )\text{d}x,
$$
which turns out to be hypergeometric series. So is the computation. Besides, a challenging [version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794044/) seems to be essentially the same. But I couldn't come over
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} s}\Bigg|_{s=1/3}\int_{0}^{1} x^{s-1}
\,_2F_1\left ( \frac23,\frac23;\frac43;1-x\right )\text{d}x
$$
appeared in
$$
\,_4F_3\left ( \frac13,\frac13,\frac23,\frac23;
1,\frac43,\frac43;1 \right ) 
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^6 }{12\pi^2} +
\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}\,\Gamma\left ( \frac13 \right )^3} 
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{2/3}} 
\,_2F_1\left ( \frac23,\frac23;\frac43;1-x \right )\text{d}x.
$$
Intuitively believe I that they have to do with($G$ denotes Catalan's constant)
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(k)^2}{\sqrt{1-k^2} }K(k)\text{d}k
=\frac{\left ( 48G-\pi^2 \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{576\pi}\\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1-k^2)^2}{\sqrt{1-k^2} }K(k)\text{d}k
=\frac{\left ( 48G+5\pi^2 \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{144\pi}\\
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(k)\ln(1-k^2)}{\sqrt{1-k^2} }K(k)\text{d}k
=\frac{\left ( 12G-\pi^2 \right )\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{144\pi}.
\end{aligned}
*Question:* Do the related ones could be shown in different techniques? Can we produce more closed-forms of these hypergeometric series?

Comment: [These formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/03/01/05/) for $\,_{q+1} F_q(1)$ may help

Answer (score 1):

We can have
$$
\,_4F_3\left ( \frac14,\frac14,\frac12,\frac12;1,\frac54,\frac54;1 \right )
=\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^4 }{64\pi}  
+\frac{\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^2 }{4\sqrt{2}\pi^{5/2} } 
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x)\ln\left ( \frac{1-x}{1+x}  \right ) }{\sqrt{x(1-x^2)} }\text{d}x.
$$